# strtok() is not responding in netbeans IDE

Tags: c++, netbeans

i am testing an explode() function in netbeans 8.1.
as follows:

```html
array explode(const char * delimiter, const char * str, unsigned int limit = 0){
        
        array out;                 //my custom struct 
        
        str = strtok(const_cast<char*>(str), delimiter);
        int tokens = 0; 
        
        while(str){
            cout << str;    //this line is my nightmere, as it does not display
            str = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
            out[tokens + 1] = str;

            tokens++;
 }     
        
        return out;
   }
```

above snippet built successfully in netbeans 8.1. however, upon run, the error message was:

cygdrive/C/Program Files/NetBeans 8.1/ide/bin/nativeexecution/dorun.sh: line 33:  6036 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) sh "${SHFILE}"
    Press [Enter] to close the terminal ...

Comment: how did you call this function? What data you pass in?

Comment: like this : array result = explode(",", "Socket, send, 1 2 3");

Comment: You're trying to write to a string literal which is read-only, even if you `const_cast` it... use a different `char*` to hold the return value of `strtok` instead of the original pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the key to your question is this, from the comment:

```
array result = explode(",", "Socket, send, 1 2 3");
```

meaning that the `const char *` is a string literal, likely allocated in an initialized data segment of the executable and mapped read-only. This means that your program genuinely *cannot* change the contents of the literal, and using `const_cast` as you do is illegal.

You should be able to investigate the core file which your error message told you was created, and you'll find that inside `strtok` it tried to write a zero into your string, to terminate the first token, and failed because writing to that memory is not permitted.

Summary: you can't use `const_cast` to make something writeable when it genuinely isn't.